# why am I getting the cannot find symbol when passing an array into a method

Tags: java

can someone please tell me why I am getting this error when compiling?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class StatsCalculator
{
public static void main (String[]args)
{
    programHeader();
    randomNo(random);
    printArray(random);
}

public static void programHeader()//writes program header
{
    System.out.println("****************");
    System.out.println("Stats calculator");
    System.out.println("****************");
}

public static int[] randomNo(int[] random)// fills an array with 10 random numbers
{
      random = new int[10];
    for (int i=0; i< random.length; i++){
        int randomNumber= (int) (Math.random()*10)+1;
        random[i] = randomNumber;
    }
    return random;




}

public static int[] printArray (int[] random)//prints array
{
    System.out.println("Your ten random values are: ");
    for (int i=0; i<random.length; i++){
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(random));
    }
    return random;


}
```

}

I am writing a simple program to fill and array with 10 random numbers 1-10 and then calculate the sum, mean, mode and median of all the random numbers but i can get the methods to work just to fill the array and to print the array.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where do you define `random` in your main? If you are creating it in your `randomNo()` why are you passing an `Array` in?

Comment: just add this line to the beginning of your `main` method `int[] random = randomNo(new int[10]);`

Answer (score 0):

You should get return value of `randomNo()` then pass it to next method. This may help you:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StatsCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        programHeader();
        int[] random = randomNo();
        printArray(random);
    }

    public static void programHeader()//writes program header
    {
        System.out.println("****************");
        System.out.println("Stats calculator");
        System.out.println("****************");
    }

    public static int[] randomNo()// fills an array with 10 random numbers
    {
        int[] random = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
            int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
            random[i] = randomNumber;
        }
        return random;


    }

    public static int[] printArray(int[] random)//prints array
    {
        System.out.println("Your ten random values are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(random));
        }
        return random;


    }
}
```